# how can i download articles from sites?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I must download (for example 1000) random articles from wikipedia, and later using Html Agility Pack, remove from html files/strings remove all html/scripts tags. How can i download it? Has this library any tool for download articles from www?
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Use can use [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx). For example:

```
 var site = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://google.com");
```

Comment: yes, but i must download 1000 articles from wikipedia. For example:
i must download article from URL: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sport
and i must download article from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basketball

Random 1000 articles.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a crawler tool to grab 1000 urls in wikipedia and use this HtmlWeb in HtmlAgilityPack:

```
string Url = "http://something";
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);
```